# Minkowski problem for polytopes: the origin of necessary condition

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, ho.history-overview, polytopes

Minkowski's uniqueness theorem for polytopes concerns the specification of the shape of a polytope by the directions and measures of its facets.

> **Theorem (Minkowski)**. Let $A_i$ be positive faces areas and $n_i$ distinct,
> noncoplanar unit face normals,
> $i=1,\ldots,k$.
> Then if $\sum_{i=1}^k A_i  n_i = 0$, there is a closed convex polyhedron
> whose faces areas uniquely realize those areas and normals.

Has the necessary condition $\sum_{i=1}^k A_i  n_i = 0$ arisen before as a separate fact? In he paper [A short survey on Newton polytopes, tropical geometry and ring of conditions of algebraic torus](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07001.pdf)
by Kiumars Kaveh and A. G. Khovanskii this statement is called *Pascal’s theorem*:

> A classical theorem from geometry (attributed to Pascal) tells us...

Is this attribution correct?

**EDIT:** Askold Khovanskii answered that this statement is an obvious corrolary of Pascal's law, that is way he called it *Pascal’s theorem*.